# How do I write my ETL to behave based on Oracle UNDO setting?

Tags: java, oracle, etl, undo, database-administration

I am enhancing a java based ETL software. One of the issues with this tool in Oralce installations is that when massive deletes happen during ETL, even though I use a smaller batch size with intermediate commits, the batch runs out of UNDO space. In my current production scenario, there exists a hard limit of 4GB.

So, now, say, my program tries delete 10000 records from a parent table, committing after every 1000 records and each record deletion, cascade deletes 1 million records from 5 child tables, I've 1000x5x1000,000 deletes happening per batch/commit. I want my software to be smarter than this - I want it to figure out Oracle UNDO space, estimate how many deletes would be triggered and limit batch size accordingly. How do I do this? How do I figure UNDO related information using a query?

Comment: If you're doing something that uses all your undo then you should really increase it. Not helpful I know but a hard limit of 4GB seems tiny. I've just been through a few databases and the sizes are 50GB, 28GB, 38GB, 126GB and 44GB.

Comment: What error do you get? ORA-1555?

Comment: maybe truncate is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4GB is nothing. The correct approach is to increase the UNDO space.

Mind you, massive deletes are also to be discouraged, and it's well worth looking into ways of eliminating that.

Comment: well..I am not exactly in control of how many deletes.. it would depend on data dependencies. (Say, you delete order type A from types table, you might wipe out a million orders and order items, but deleting type B, might wipe out 10million orders and order items).

Comment: If that's the sort of situation that you have to deal with, then partitioning by order type and performing partition drop or truncate might be efficient. However it seems like an odd operation, to delete orders.

Comment: not exactly deleting orders - that was just an analogy. But, this is more of a DBA thing, isn't it? Not in the scope of an application?

Comment: Specifying adequate to undo space is the responsibility of both. You say how much you need, and the DBA checks that the request is reasonable and provides that much. 4gb is clearly inadequate though, and if your DBA advises that you submit lots of commits to reduce the resource usage then they're wrong.

Comment: how do I calculate my UNDO space requirement? It is an ETL tool, all it does it a delete on a parent table.. and the number of deletes that could happen will depend on the number of qualifying records in children table.

Comment: Start with the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/undo.htm